# Can I get an explanation on a directive and an assembly reference c#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I was messing around with my code on line 8

```
public GameObject GetEnemyPrefab() 
{ 
    return enemyPrefab;
}
```

what I want to do is only call the sprite renderer for the Prefab I get this error “missing a using directive or assembly reference”

I was wondering how do I only call for the sprite renderer and if someone could explain "missing directive or assembly" to me. Like what do Directive and assembly mean?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu(menuName = "Enemy Wave Config")]
public class WaveConfig : ScriptableObject 
{
    [SerializeField] GameObject enemyPrefab;
    [SerializeField] GameObject pathPrefab;
    [SerializeField] float timeBetweenSpawns = 0.5f;
    [SerializeField] float spawnRandomFactor = 0.3f;
    [SerializeField] int numberOfEnemies = 5;
    [SerializeField] float moveSpeed = 2f;

    public GameObject GetEnemyPrefab() { return enemyPrefab; }

    public GameObject GetPathPrefab() { return pathPrefab; }

    public List<Transform> GetWaypoints()
    {
        var waveWaypoints = new List<Transform>();

        foreach (Transform child in pathPrefab.transform)
        {
            waveWaypoints.Add(child);
        }

        return waveWaypoints;
    }

    public float GetTimeBetweenSpawns() { return timeBetweenSpawns; }
    public float GetSpawnRandomFactor() { return spawnRandomFactor; }
    public int GetNumberOfEnemies() { return numberOfEnemies; }
    public float GetMoveSpeed() { return moveSpeed; }
}
```

“missing a using directive or assembly reference”

Comment: I`m assuming there is some more detailed error message somewhere. Can you include it? Seems you're probably missing a reference to a .dll-file or something similar, but it's hard to tell just from your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full error message tells you what's happening on line 8:

> Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SerializeFieldAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

It doesn't recognize the `[SerializeField]` attribute because your project does not have a reference to an Assembly that contains it.

In this case specifically it means that your project does not reference the UnityEngine assembly which you can fix from the Nuget Package Manager console tab with:

```bsh
Install-Package UnityEngine
```

Comment: Yeah you shouldn't do this via NuGet .. if UnityEngine isn't found probably something isn't installed correctly in general. Also shouldn't it in that case already throw an exception at the line `using UnityEngine;`?

Comment: Thank you this helped me understand the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Using directive is a C# keyword that allow the use of types in a namespace without using their fully qualified names (type + all namespaces).
So for example instead of writing in your code each time

```
System.Collections.ArrayList myArrayList;
System.Collections.ArrayList myArrayList2;
```

You can utilize using directive

```
using System.Collections;
ArrayList myArrayList;
ArrayList myArrayList2;
```

You can get more examples at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive.

Assembly reference is a way to tell the compiler that in this project you want to use classes and functions from some other library. So for example your project must reference UnityEngine if u want to use type GameObject because its defined in that library.

In your case you might need to add reference to NuGet Package.
Full error massage should contain the type that is missing, you should google up the library that contains missing type and add reference to your project.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/install-and-use-a-package-in-visual-studio.